# Revamp old asp.net 4.0 web app with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I just landed my new job and I have been given an old asp.net 4.0 ecommerce web application hooked up with the company's ERP software to work on.
The thing is it's really old and it definitely needs some help on the design and integrating Bootstrap would help a lot. 
So I downloaded Bootstrap and added the files to the project and I want to change the asp classes from this :

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="homeButtons" CssClass="homeButtons" DefaultButton="btnHomePageWebsites">
```

To this :

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="homeButtons" CssClass="btn-group btn-group-lg" DefaultButton="btnHomePageWebsites">
```

Is it the right way of doing it?
Now, as I did not build it, I would not want to screw up the whole app by changing the wrong classes!
Someone told me I could do something with Sass and @extend and rename the Bootstrap classes to the existing ones? Would it be better?
Finally, which pages should I start with? Master pages and then .aspx/.ascx?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, the ID attribute should not be CSS classes

Comment: thanks, let me edit it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not change the ID of anything, just their CssClass. If their ID is used somewhere else (which is likely) it will break, and IDs are supposed to be unique, which is not the case of classes
2. It's probably much simpler to just implement the classes in your code than to modify Bootstrap's SASS, but I don't know a lot about CSS precompilers, so I can't much about that.
3. I would suggest beginning with the master page